# React native runnig error on ios device

Tags: ios, node.js, react-native, npm, react-native-ios

I am trying to run react native code to iphone, however it shows the  following message.

The following code runs on Android normally, and on expo fine too, but it does not run on physical device.

Please help me.

> ```
> E:\reactnative\cd webview
>
> E:\reactnative\webview>react-native run-ios
> Scanning folders for symlinks in E:\reactnative\webview\node_modules (38ms)
> Found Xcode project webview.xcodeproj
>
> spawnSync xcrun ENOENT
>
> E:\reactnative\webview>
> ```

Comment: which react-native-cli version are u using?

Comment: @BigPun86 i'm using version 2.0.1
`react-native-cli: 2.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-native-cli version 0.1.7 then you could either

Rollback to 0.1.7 (do not use '--verbose' argument)

```
npm install -g react-native-cli@0.1.7
```

or try it with the latest which might be fixed

```
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

There was a regression in 0.1.8, reported here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5169

Comment: i will try above solution but it still not working
showing the same error.